# Add customize field in blocklayered

Tags: module, prestashop, custom-fields

I have problem with add new custom field to search in blocklayered Prestashop.
How I can add new search field with custom type such as:

1. add textbox to search product by name
2. add textbox to search product by producer
3. add textbox to search product by quality

I tried to add custom field but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

in this case it's necessary to rebuild search functions located in Search.php class (classes/Search.php)

it's necessary to include these fields to search queries.